# Is there a way to change the back button color when using the navigation controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an iOS app in Xcode using the navigation controller view. I am wondering if there is a way to change the color of the back button that is set to the iOS blue by default. And if so, is there a way to make it a specific RGB value?

Comment: Shoot, I meant to use this one: [How to change the color of backBarButtonItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7497543) Copy-paste error.

Comment: Hey thanks! Any idea where I would go to enter the code to change that? I tried my ViewController.swift and the AppDelegate.Swift files. Would I have to create a separate swift file and reference it to the back button some how?

Comment: You would do it in the view controller that originates the push, or somewhere before that, but after the navigation controller is created. See [KKendall's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12042464/603977) on the question that I linked second.